# Trying to wrap CALL function fails

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, call

I wanted a slightly augmented wrapper for the CALL function, one that changes the cmd.exe window title so I know what it's doing, and writes the output to a log file. My mycall.bat file looks like this:

```
title %1
call %1 > %1.log

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 GOTO :SUCCESS
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO :ERROR

:SUCCESS
@ECHO "   MYCALL %1: Completed successfully."
EXIT /B 0

:ERROR
@ECHO "   MYCALL %1: An ERROR has occurred, errorlevel: %ERRORLEVEL%"
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

The main caller file, TestCall.bat, is this:

```
mycall test1.bat
mycall test2.bat
mycall test3.bat
```

Each of those files, test1.bat, test2.bat, test3.bat has just one line, i.e. ECHO "Test1" for the first, ECHO "Test2" for the 2nd, etc.

When I run the TestCall.bat file from a cmd.exe window, I only see "Test1" echoed; the other files never seem to run, nothing on screen, no log file created. My sense is that this problem is some error handling issue, but there shouldn't be any.  TestCall.bat does the first call successfully, then just seems to stop - I do see the "MYCALL test1.bat: Completed successfully." message.

Maybe I've been staring at it too long, am missing something obvious - any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to use `call` when starting other batch files. `call mycall test1`

Comment: Take a look at the `Start` command usage information, (open up a command prompt window and enter `start /?`).